# when TEXT isn't enough for a record entry?

Tags: mysql, text

My site allows users to submit **After Action Reports** and yesterday someone set the new record with a **~48,000** character beast of a report. While that's still only 74% of the `TEXT` maximum character count, it made me wonder what should be done when someone wants to submit something that exceeds the 65k limit...? It's bound to happen eventually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one of the larger TEXT types. A LONGTEXT will accept 4 GB of data. A MEDIUMTEXT will store 16 MB of data.

Answer (score 0):

you might start storing the data in text or xml files on the server and link to them using sql? either that or use multiple records, i don't see many other options.

Comment: Storing on the filesystem gets difficult to maintain referential integrity.  The topic is a holy war when figuring out how to deal with images...

Comment: really? i didn't think anyone stored images as binary. i thought that text and blob have the same limit?